# Django.core.exeptions.ImproperlyConfigured: the included URLconf does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django, django-urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
import Echo.urls
import users.urls
#this is the urls
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('Echo.urls', namespace='Echo')),
path('users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users'))
]
users/urls.py
"""Defines URL patterns for users"""

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login#importing default login view
from . import views

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
# Login page
url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'users/login.html'},
name='login'),
# Logout page
url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
# Registration page
url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register')

]
Echo/urls.py
#Defines Urls for Echo

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'Echo'
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('companies/', views.business, name='companies'),
path('company/<int:pk>', 
views.BusinessDetail.as_view(),name='BusinessDetail')

]

error message

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in 
url_patterns
iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in 
wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in 
inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 
390, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 
377, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 
72, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in 
check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in 
check_resolver
return check_method()
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in 
check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in 
__get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in 
url_patterns
raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 
'mysite.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid 
patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular 
import.
```

help?
anything will appreciate.
django on visual studio
i added all url files
i also added the error message
i have checked all grammar and nothing seems to be wrong
all advice is appreciated
python updated
pip updated
bootstrap is installed
error on missing pattern
code has information on the error
error on missing pattern
code has information on the error
error on missing pattern
code has information on the error
error on missing pattern
code has information on the error
error on missing pattern
code has information on the error

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have _any_ patterns in the `Echo.urls` and `users.urls` file?

Comment: Yes I do well the Echo.urls file workder perfectly but when I started the app users and included the URLs of users it suddenly gave me this error and I don’t know how to fix it yet

Comment: So you should define `urlpatterns` in your `users.urls` as well to get rid of this error.

Comment: urlpatterns = [ url(r‘^login/$’, login, {‘template_name’: ‘users/login.html’}, name=‘login’),]

Comment: It also has a typeError: ‘module’ object not iterable

Comment: Are my paths the paths the problem?

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and include your `users.urls` code, as well as the **full** traceback message.

Comment: It’s edited answers please

Answer (score 0):

The last part of traceback is the problem here: you have a **circular import**.

Simply change your `urls.py` as:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('Echo.urls', namespace='Echo')),
    path('users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users'))
]
```

(remove `Echo.urls` and `users.urls` import)